# Rewrite URL in php using htaccess file with root directory

Tags: .htaccess

Show URL like this: 
`localhost/test/view/admin/process.php?action=dashboard`

I want show my URL like  this below:
`localhost/test/general/dashboard/`

Test is root directory,
general is like module name and
dashboard is page name

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would get the answer pretty quickly if you just googled the title of your question... Or used StackOverflow's search function. Or just had a look at the related questions... Rewriting URLs is *such* a common question that it has been answered countless times.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`RewriteEngine on`

`RewriteRule ^/general/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /view/admin/process.php?action=$1 [L]`

Your question has been answered countless times, googled before ask.

Answer (score -1):

RewriteRule localhost/test/general/(.*)/ localhost/test/view/admin/process.php?action=$1 [L]

bad url format